# What HTML files should be edited in cordova?

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

I have seen a few references to this topic, but it's not 100% clear to me.

Inside the top level of a cordova project you have these folders '.cordova', 'merges', 'platforms', 'plugins', 'www'. I would think you edit the top level 'www' folder and it would update the files inside `platforms\<platform>\assets\www` because editing files directly in this path get overwrote, from what I have read and I experienced this once before deploying an app.

I can't find documentation on this (searching cordova update project just covers updating cordova itself, at least from what I am seeing maybe I'm being blind here).

How do the files in the root 'www' update the project files? I am sure there is a command for this but is it true I have to run an update command every time I make an edit in say Dreamweaver, because when I make an update it obviously doesnt make changes into the  directory because it doesnt have anything telling it to.

So what I am asking.

1. You should edit the html/css/javascript inside the cordova projects root 'www'?
2. What are some solutions to updating the platform code from the main files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the content of `www` folder in main project directory and run `cordova build` command to copy these files to your platform specific directories. So the process will be like

- Edit the content of www folder in project directory.
- Debug the changes with any browser or emulator like Ripple.
- Run cordova build command to test it in Android emulator or in a real device.

To use cordova command line tools, you need to install cordova command line interface. It can be found [here](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html).